# Qt, QML, ColorImage is not a type

Tags: qt, qml, pyside2

I made a QML button component and I used a component named `ColorImage` for the icon. After searching for a way to change image color. I found out that Qt no longer support [ColorOverlay](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-coloroverlay.html)

Hover, I just typed in 'color' in Qt Design Studio and `ColorImage` popped up. I tried to find documentation online but couldn't find anything. However, when I decided to try it, it just works as I expected:

This is the relevant code from my button:

```
    contentItem: ColorImage {
        id: buttonIcon
        source: imageSource
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        height: parent.height
        color: iconColor
        anchors.fill: actionBarButton
        anchors.margins: 4
    }
```

When the `hovered` state from the button becomes `true` it enables the following state:

```
State {
            when: (hovered && !checked)
            name: "hoveredNotChecked"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: buttonIcon
                color: "white"
            }

            PropertyChanges {
                target: buttonBackground
                color: iconColor
            }
        },
```

which swaps the icon and the background color on the button.

This works in the preview of the Qt Designer. However, when I try to run it from Pyside, it tells me: `ColorImage is not a type` and simply fails to load the button.

I tried to find documentation about `ColorImage` to figure out maybe there's an import missing. However, I could not turn up anything. Qt Designer's internal help did not turn up anything as well. It is as if this component doesn't exist. But it does, and it works in Design Studio.

Here is the full code for my button:

```
Button {
    id: actionBarButton

    property color iconColor: "red"
    property color backgroundColor: "blue"
    property string toolTipText: "Play video!"
    property string imageSource: "images/round_play_arrow_white_36dp.png"
    property string imageSourceChecked: "images/round_play_arrow_white_36dp.png"

    states: [
        State {
            when: (hovered && !checked)
            name: "hoveredNotChecked"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: buttonIcon
                color: "white"
            }

            PropertyChanges {
                target: buttonBackground
                color: iconColor
            }
        },
        State {
            when: (hovered && checked)
            name: "hoveredChecked"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: buttonIcon
                source: imageSourceChecked
                color: "white"
            }

            PropertyChanges {
                target: buttonBackground
                color: iconColor
            }
        },
        State {
            when: checked
            name: "checked"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: buttonIcon
                source: imageSourceChecked
            }
        }
    ]

    transitions: Transition {

        ColorAnimation {
            duration: 300
        }
    }

    contentItem: ColorImage {
        id: buttonIcon
        source: imageSource
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        height: parent.height
        color: iconColor
        anchors.fill: actionBarButton
        anchors.margins: 4
    }

    onHoveredChanged: {

    }
    background: Rectangle {
        id: buttonBackground
        color: backgroundColor
        anchors.fill: actionBarButton
    }

    ToolTip.delay: 1000
    ToolTip.timeout: 5000
    ToolTip.visible: hovered
    ToolTip.text: actionBarButton.toolTipText
}
```

This is how it looks in the designer:
[image: Here is how it looks in the designer]

Can someone help me figure out why it complains about `ColorImage`not being a type when I try to launch?

Edit:

The imports in the file above:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
```

Comment: ColorImage or ColorOverlay? Does it work with Qt Quick Designer? Qt Quick Designer is different from Qt Design Studio. Also show the imports.

Comment: @eyllanesc >ColorImage or ColorOverlay?

 `ColorImage` It's in the code I provided above. As I said, I looked for `ColorOverlay` but it turns out it's no longer supported.

>Does it work with Qt Quick Designer? It works with the studio. I have no idea how to check in Designer. I opened it up in Qt Creator and it doesn't recognize `ColorImage` as a type. But the Designer does.

Comment: @eyllanesc It's possible that `ColorImage` is a Qt Design Studio component. Because when I open my `ActionBarButton.qml` file in it, it says "This file should be opened in Design mode. If that's the case, is there some way to import this component elsewhere... Or maybe achieve the same behavior with a different component?

I'll edit the post to add my imports in a second.

Comment: `ColorOverlay` is available again in Qt 6.2 in Qt5Compat: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qt5compat-graphicaleffects-coloroverlay.html It will eventually be replaced by Qt Quick MultiEffect https://marketplace.qt.io/products/qt-quick-multieffect

Comment: Also, it appears ColorImage is a Qt internal private component: https://github.com/qt/qtdeclarative/blob/dev/src/quickcontrols2impl/qquickcolorimage.cpp It doesn't appear to be supported for non-internal use. If you really want to use it, try importing `QtQuick.Controls.impl`

Comment: @DavidK.Hess That being said. What should I do now? I installed Qt about a week ago. So I figure I have the latest version. How can I import `CoverOverlay`? And if 6.2 is not out yet. Then what should I do in the meantime? Is it possible to just make `ColorImage` work?

Comment: See my edit to my comment above on what might make it available to you. Qt 6.2 was released on September 30 of this year: https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_6.2_Release

Comment: @DavidK.Hess "If you really want to use it, try importing QtQuick.Controls.impl" this indeed worked. I added `2.15` because it asked for a version number. I know it's not the best solution, but so far it does what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ColorImage is a Qt internal private component:

https://github.com/qt/qtdeclarative/blob/dev/src/quickcontrols2impl/qquickcolorimage.cpp

It doesn't appear to be supported for non-internal use.

If you really want to use it, try `import QtQuick.Controls.impl 2.15`

Note that ColorOverlay is available again in Qt 6.2 in Qt5Compat:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qt5compat-graphicaleffects-coloroverlay.html

It will eventually be replaced by Qt Quick MultiEffect:

https://marketplace.qt.io/products/qt-quick-multieffect

Comment: Thank you this helped solved my issue!